# Excel IF that has three condtions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have an Excel question.

I have 4 columns in Excel A2, B2, C2, and D2

```
A2= proposed cost
B2= Company cost
C2= actual cost
D2 = Total

D1 = a given dollar amount of $1500
```

I would like to know how to write a formula that allows the user to enter a value in A2 that will be subtracted from D2 but when the user enters a value in B2 it will override that original subtraction and only subtract from D2 and when the user finally enters the actual cost it will only subtract the value entered in C2 from D2.

ex: If the proposed cost is $1000 I want the total to reflect $500 but if the company cost is only $900 I want the new total to equal $600. lastly, if (at a later date) the actual cost is only a $500 expense I want the total to then show $1000.

This is the formula that I have so far... but it is not working

```
'=IF(A2=TRUE,SUM(D1-A2),"",IF(B2=TRUE,SUM(D1-B2),"",IF(C2=TRUE,SUM(D1- C2),"")))'
```

Any help would be most appreciated. This is the first time i have posted so please let me know if more information/ clarification is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, it sounds like your problem is just managing your if statements correctly. try

```
D3=IF(C3="",IF(B3="",IF(A3="",D1,D1-A3),D1-B3),D1-C3)
```

in this example, c3 overrides b3 which overrides a3, and if all are blank than d1 is the answer. Take a look at my screenshot for out I set up my sheet in this example.[image: screenshot]

Cheers,

Comment: please don't forget to click the checkmark if you like my answer. my low-level account could use some rep points. if you've got questions feel free to pm me with the email posted in my profile desc.